# Tamaño fuente en barra menú Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Me gustaría incrementar el tamaño de la fuente de la barra de menú de Spring Tool Suite (eclipse) pero no sé dónde se modifica este parámetro.
He ido a

```
Window Menu -> Preferences -> General > Appearance > Color and Fonts > Basic > Text Font > Edit & Apply
```

Pero esto no modifica el tamaño de la barra de menú:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se puede cambiar el tamaño de la barra de menús?

Gracias